# Alias lost after new shell spawned

Tags: linux, bash

After logging into my account in linux - I am able to use all the alias I have created in my .bash_profile file.

But after I am executing a simple script (setter.sh) with the command:
  cleartool setview view_name

All the alias are getting lost - this could be possibly because cleartool spawns a new shell 
Query is:

1. How to determine how many shells are spawned currently - can I know at which nesting level am I currently in - if a script works in such a way that is spawns new shell?.
2. How to retain the alias values after launching new shell - Like in the above case?
3. If I try to ensure that .bash_profile get's re-executed as part of the script by adding source .bash_profile - even then - the alias setting is not taking place?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have googled on `.bash_profile` and you would have [found](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile) that `.bash_profile` is for *login* shells, `.bashrc` is for *interactive* shells, and that shell scripts don't use them.

Within shell scripts, better use functions (which you'll have to define) than aliases.

The shell level of [subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) is available thru the `SHLVL` variable.

Take time to read the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: +1 also, you can export functions so that they'll appear in subshells: `export -f function_name`